# How can I adjust matrices into the same ItemSize and aligned well in Notebook?

Tags: matrix, formatting

[image]

I typed three matrices, but they are not aligned well, and the `Items` in one matrix are also not aligned well and with differenct `ItemSize`.

How can I adjust them into the same `ItemSize`?

Better is that I can click the buttons/menus to do the thing something like `align paragraph` in `writing assistant`.

And I found the matrix typed is `GridBox`, so I can adjust them by options of Grid.

Comment: Have you tried `//TableForm`? Does it help?

Comment: @RodLm I haven't tried that, I'll try that, I wonder whether there are some palletes such like writing assistant or buttons or menus to do such align or adjust things.

Comment: So you want actually to "type" aligned or "show" aligned?

Comment: @RodLm "Show" aligned, maybe after finishing typing them, and then click one button, they'are shown aligned, of course better could "aligned" when typing.

Comment: Does `TableForm[{Y, P, R}, TableAlignments -> Center]` help?

Comment: You could also take a look at `TableSpacing->{,}`.

Comment: @RodLm `TableAlignments->Center` seems not affect `-Sin[u] and Cos[u]` not aligned well, not only the align of three matrices, but also the rows of one matrix.

Comment: @RodLm Ok, I found the matrix typed is with `GridBox`, so I can adjust them with options of Grid

Answer (score 1):

`Grid` will do the job. First `Join` all the matrices and then use `Grid`.

```
Y = {{Cos[u], Sin[u], 0}, {-Sin[u], Cos[u], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
P = {{Cos[v], 0, -Sin[v]}, {0, 1, 0}, {Sin[v], 0, Cos[v]}};
R = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[w], -Sin[w]}, {0, Sin[w], Cos[w]}};

Grid[Join[Y,P,R]]
```

[image: grid1]

You can use `TableForm` also.

Now when you want to put the name, its a bit different. What I have done here is adding an extra column to each matrices with their mane and then `Join` and `Grid`.

```
tag[name_] := {"", name, ""};
(*the length of this row must be equal to column length of the matrix*)
matname[name_, mat_] := MapThread[Insert, {mat, tag[name], Table[1, {Length[mat]}]}];

Grid[Join[matname["Y =", Y], matname["P =", P], matname["R =", R]]]
```

[image: grid2]

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the comments you can use `GridBox`:

```
GridBox[{{1, 1}, {1, 1000}}, ColumnWidths -> 2.5] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

Then you can copy&paste it, add parentheses and additional columns and rows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> respectively:

[image]

`ColumnsEqual -> True` option can also be useful.